# Ruby form helper get sucked with older value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I got blocked while trying to get the right value after value overwriting before submitting the form from a CircleCreateService
From my Circle create Service I have this:

```
def step_trigger(case_action)
  case case_action
    when 'User never create a circle'
      'ncreate'
    when 'User has created once'
      'onecreate'
    when 'User has created many'
      'mcreated'
  end
end
```

And this is what I saved into my database. So my problem is, from my form, when I am trying to edit the Circle, how can I get the old value from the db using a helper method to render corresponding option based on the retrieved data from my db?

This is my **helper method**:

```
def get_old_cirle_option(options)
  case options
    when 'ncreate'
      'User never create a circle'
    when 'oncecreate'
      'User has created once'
    when 'mcreated'
      'User has created many'
  end
end
```

And in my **form** I use this:

```
<%= select_tag :c_options, 
options_from_collection_for_select(
get_old_cirle_option(@circe.state)), 
class: "form-control" %>
```

the it says: `undefined method`map' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  tap`

Comment: `options_from_collection_for_select` expects an `Enumerable` as the first argument but there are clearly other issues as well. First `get_old_cirle_option(@circe.state)` is returning `nil` which means `@circe.state` is not one of `'ncreate'`,`'oncecreate'`, or `'mcreated'`. Second I have no idea what your intention was for this to begin with.

Comment: First thank you for your reply. What I wanted is to be able to edit the cercle state because I will have a large filter based on the cercle state for my users. but I can't save them into the db, and in the mean time the user should be able to understand, that's why I used text, from the form and overwrite in the service before saving

Comment: put a default condition to check the value and the return value should be an array instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

`options_from_collection_for_select` needs 4 parameters:

- `collection`, which must be array
- `value_method`
- `text_method`
- `selected`, which is optional and gets `nil` if omitted

Also, `get_old_cirle_option(@circe.state)` returns `nil` in your case.

Comment: You said it needs 3 parameters but you listed 4 (collection, value_method, text_method, selected). Can you please clarify?

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select

Comment: I don't even know if your answer is correct (I've never programmed in Rails), but I edited it to improve its formatting.

Comment: Well tnx for editing. He got answer. Someone commented same under his question.

Comment: Seems like the actual question is "how can I get the old value from the db using a helper method to render corresponding option based on the retrieved data from my db?" which has nothing to do with the error itself